# How to collapse/expand accordion in a Q&A form after input selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Not sure if that's the correct vocabulary, but here's what I'm trying accomplish. I'm working with a team on this big multi-page Q&A application, my task is make one particular page use the least amount of screen real estate as possible.

I'm using an accordion, each one has a question inside, and next to each question is a question mark which changes to check mark after the question is answered.

I have all that already completed which you can see here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".accordion_head").click(function() {
    if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
      $(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
      $(".updown").text('\u25BC');
    }
    if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
      $(this).children(".updown").text('\u25BC');
    } else {
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
      $(this).children(".updown").text('\u25B2');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion_container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.accordion_head {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px 0 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.accordion_body {
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 1em;
}

.accordion_body p {
  padding: 18px 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.check-mark, .question-mark {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -4px !important;
}

.check-mark {
  border-color: #c4db30;
  color: #c4db30;
}

.question-mark {
  border-color: #086cff;
  color: #086cff;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.plusminus {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<form action="demo_form.aspx" method="get">
  <div class="accordion_container">
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> What type of sensors are required?
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark" aria-hidden="true"></span>        
        </div>
        
        <div class="accordion_body" style="display: block;">
          <select>
            <option value="sensors">None Selected</option>
            <option value="sensors">Photocell On</option>
            <option value="sensors">Off Control Only</option>
            <option value="sensors">Photocell On / Off Control Only</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion_head"><span class="plusminus">&#9660;</span> Please select if the below products are present / required.
        <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span> 
        </div>
        
        <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="nWifi"> nWifi (nLight)<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="nLightFixtures"> nLightFixtures<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="xCella"> xCella (LC&D)<br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="DaylightHarvesting"> Daylight Harvesting<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="xPoint"> xPoint (LC&D)<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="GraphicsSoftare"> Graphics Sofware<br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> What type of construction is this? 
          <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span> 
        </div>
        
        <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
          <input type="radio" name="contruction" value="NewConstruction" /> New Construction<br>
          <input type="radio" name="construction" value="Retrofit" /> Retrofit<br>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> Scope of work 
          <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span> 
        </div>

        <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
          <input type="radio" name="work" value="AllAreas" /> New Construction<br>
          <input type="radio" name="work" value="Retrofit" /> Retrofit<br>
        </div>   

        <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> BMS Integration
          <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span>  
        </div>
        
        <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input type="checkbox" name="bms-integration" value="BACnetIP"> BACnet IP<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="bms-integration" value="BACnetMSTP"> BACnet MSTP<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="bms-integration" value="Modbus"> Modbus<br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input type="checkbox" name="bms-integration" value="LonWorks"> LonWorks<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="bms-integration" value="Metasys"> Metasys<br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="bms-integration" value="Other"> Other<br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> Dimming Information
          <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span> 
        </div>
        
        <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
          <input type="checkbox" name="dimming-information" value="TenV"> 0-10V<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="dimming-information" value="DALI"> DALI<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="dimming-information" value="TwoW"> 2W<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="dimming-information" value="threeW"> 3W<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="dimming-information" value="Other"> Other<br>
          </div>
      </div><!-- end .col-xs-6 -->
  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
      
      <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> Voltages Used 
        <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span> 
      </div>
      
      <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="voltage" value="volt120"> 120 / 277<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="voltage" value="volt208"> 208<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="voltage" value="volt347"> 347<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="voltage" value="volt480"> 480<br>
      </div>
      
      <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> Interfaces 
        <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span> 
      </div>
      
      <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="interfaces" value="BAS"> BAS / HVAC<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="interfaces" value="AV"> A/V System<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="interfaces" value="Shades"> Shades<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="interfaces" value="LightingControlSystems"> Other Lighting Control Systems<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="interfaces" value="Other"> Other<br>
      </div>
      
      <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> Maintain switch ganging configurations? 
        <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span> 
      </div>
      
      <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="switch ganging" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="switch ganging" value="No"> No<br>
      </div>   
      
      <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> Emergency Design 
        <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span> 
      </div>
      
      <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="emergency design" value="Generator"> Generator<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="emergency design" value="Battery"> Battery<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="emergency design" value="GTD"> GTD<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="emergency design" value="Shunting Required"> Shunting Required<br>
      </div> 
      
      <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> Energy Code Compliance (Also Provide Version if Selected) 
        <span class="question-mark" aria-hidden="true">?</span> 
      </div>
      
      <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="energy code compliance" value="IECC"> IECC<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="energy code compliance" value="ASHRAE"> ASHRAE 90.1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="energy code compliance" value="Title24"> Title 24<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="energy code compliance" value="Other"> Other<br>
      </div>       
      
    </div><!-- end .col-xs-6 -->
  </div><!-- end .accordion_container -->
</form>
```

Here's where I'm stuck.

Once I select an answer for a question, I want the accordion to collapse to the next question, of course, it will only apply to single answer fields.

1. How do I expand the next question after I select an answer for the previous question?
2. How do I change the question mark to a check mark after I select an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround each "accordion" with a div (i gave it a class accordion_main)

add the check mark classes and remove the question class.

The html will look like this:

```
<div class="accordion_main">
                    <div class="accordion_head"><span class="updown">&#9660;</span> What type of sensors are required? <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion_body" style="display: block;">
                        <select>
                            <option value="sensors">None Selected</option>
                            <option value="sensors">Photocell On</option>
                            <option value="sensors">Off Control Only</option>
                            <option value="sensors">Photocell On / Off Control Only</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".accordion_head").click(function () {
    if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
        $(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
        $(".updown").text('\u25BC');
    }
    if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
        $(this).children(".updown").text('\u25BC');
    } else {
        $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
        $(this).children(".updown").text('\u25B2');
    }
});
$(".accordion_body select").change(function () {
    nextQuestion($(this));
});
$(".accordion_body input").change(function () {
    nextQuestion($(this));
});
});

function nextQuestion(currentQuestion) {
    var parentEle = currentQuestion.parents(".accordion_main");
    if (parentEle.next()) {
        parentEle.find(".question-mark").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark").removeClass("question-mark").text("");
        if (currentQuestion.attr('type') != 'checkbox') {
            if (parentEle.next().find(".accordion_head").length > 0) {
                parentEle.next().find(".accordion_head").click();
            } else {
                //there is no next--> try to go to the next colum
                parentEle.parent("div").next("div").find(".accordion_head").first().click();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w71un7v9/)

Comment: That works except for one thing, it should ignore the multiple checkboxes as those allow for more than one selection. I tried using '.attr("type", "radio")' but that didn't work.

Comment: In your example I also noticed the collapsing stops at the end of each column as oppose to continuing to the next column as it does in my example.

Comment: ok, i've added some modifications--> it will not move forward if it is a "checkbox" input, and it will go to next columns..

Comment: That works perfectly, I hope to get my JavaScript skills up to this level soon.

Answer (score 0):

Edit to address your questions (this might be a bit verbose--I wasn't concerned with elegance). You could add something like this to your $(document).ready beneath what you already have.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0nsknfx7/2/)

```
$('.accordion_container').on('change', 'input, select', function() {
    var formSection = $(this).parents('.accordion_body').first();
    updateSection(formSection);
    if ($(this).is('input[type=checkbox]')) {
        return;
    }
    formSection.prev('.accordion_head').trigger('click');
    if (formSection.next('.accordion_head').length) {
        formSection.next('.accordion_head').trigger('click');
    }
});

$('.accordion_body').each(function() {
    updateSection($(this));
});

function markSectionComplete(formSection) {
    var sectionHead = formSection.prev('.accordion_head'),
        completeHtml = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark' aria-hidden='true'></span>";
    sectionHead.find('.question-mark').replaceWith(completeHtml);
}

function markSectionIncomplete(formSection) {
    var sectionHead = formSection.prev('.accordion_head'),
        incompleteHtml = "<span class='question-mark' aria-hidden='true'>?</span>";
    sectionHead.find('.check-mark').replaceWith(incompleteHtml);
}

function sectionComplete(formSection) {
    if (formSection.find('input').length && formSection.find('input:checked').length) {
        return true;
    } else if (formSection.find('select').length && formSection.find('select').val() !== '') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function updateSection(formSection) {
    console.log(formSection.get(0));
    if (sectionComplete(formSection)) {
        markSectionComplete(formSection);
    } else {
        markSectionIncomplete(formSection);
    }
}
```

This makes some assumptions about the structure of your form, of course. For the record, I'd have probably structured the HTML differently, but I worked with what you had, save for correcting a few errors. Note particularly that you didn't have proper values for the select list options.

Comment: Trying to do the same for dropdowns as well.

Comment: For the single select dropdowns that is.

Comment: I've revised my answer to more fully address your needs. The answer you accepted (I haven't enough reputation to comment upon it) is largely fine, except that it doesn't address the condition that a user might at some point make a section incomplete again (e.g., by unchecking all checkboxes).